# Regex for validating the first letter of the last part of a URL segment

Tags: java, regex, url

Sounds like quite a cryptic question!

I'm trying to to write a quick RegEx (it'll be evaluated in Java) that will validate that the last part of a URL starts with a certain letter.

e.g.  I want to validate that the last part of the URL starts with a "P". 
i.e. Find the ***last*** occurrence of the / and **then** check the next letter is a "P"

Should validate this:

```
www.mydomain.com/browse/P123
or www.mydomain.com/browse/P987W?id=1
```

But not match  this:

```
www.mydomain.com/Product/C123
```

(for a system that uses a regex to validate so I can't code it!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular expression for the case with no query string:

```
".*/P[^/]*$"
```

which means "make sure that the final slash in the string is immediately followed by a capital P. (The leading `.*` isn't necessary, but allows you to use `Pattern.match` instead of `Pattern.find`).

To make it handle query strings too:

```
".*/P[^/?]*(\?.*)?$"
```

Comment: This won't work if the query string contains a slash.

Comment: Ah, nice. (Same thing applies to the #fragment, but that's easily added.)

Comment: Actually, just tested it (in Ruby, but still should apply) and it doesn't work. The first `.*` needs to be `[^?#]*`

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

That is surely not possible with regex. Remove the last segment (eg. `String lastSegment = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/"));` then you can check the first letter of it with regex.

Comment: It certainly is possible; see the other answer.

Comment: yep, rethinking the problem, true. But still faster with lastIndexOf()

Comment: Except the question says he doesn't have any option to use other code - *a system that uses a regex to validate so I can't code it!*. (And also your solution would break if the query string had / in it).